# How avoid NoTableManagedException on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

When I debug my GAE project on eclipse, using the defautl jdo values configuration, I´m getting the exception "NoTableManagedException" className does not seem to have been enhanced.
How can I fix it?

Here is part of the pom and the project structure:

[image]

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints-deps</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-jsr107cache</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.discovery</include>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.api</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=y
                        </jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                    <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.gaeNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-release</version>
                <configuration>

                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: How can you avoid "class has not been enhanced" ??? Why not enhance it ?

Comment: On gae and using maven I get these error, but with the google plugin, nothing happens, allways using the same code, may be something is not well configured on maven

Comment: which doesn't answer the question of whether you have enhanced your classes. You can easily check, by looking at them with a Java bytecode decompiler http://jd.benow.ca/   aka debugging the problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with gae and I thought that is more simple the mavenize process, but maybe I miss something.

Comment: Enhancing using Maven IS simple. You don't say what you've done, and what you've checked.

Comment: datanucleus-maven-plugin v4.0 is for a later version; you're using DataNucleus v3.1.x for the jars, so should use maven-datanucleus-plugin v3.1.3